org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: invalid identifier
I am migrating application from Hibernate 4 to Hibernate 5.
I have piece of code which I haven't touched:
public Integer getCount(QueryBuilder query) {
    Criteria criteria = getDao().buildCriteria(Summary.class, query);
    criteria.setProjection(count("id"));
    return ((Long) criteria.list().get(0)).intValue();
}

In logs when this is called I can see:
ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - "ORA-00904: "THIS_"."CREATED_BY_USER_ID": invalid identifier
"
ERROR controllers.UncaughtExceptionHandler - "Uncaught exception [org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException] in handler [org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod] message [could not extract ResultSet > ORA-00904: "THIS_"."CREATED_BY_USER_ID": invalid identifier
]"
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:63)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "THIS_"."CREATED_BY_USER_ID": invalid identifier

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:399)

I was able to get debugger into this piece of code and I could compare the old version of criteria and query which is working (hibernate 4) and new version of criteria and query which is not working (hibernate 5).
I can see that they are the same so the only difference which I can see is Criteria version. One if from hibernate.core 4 and second is from hibernate.core 5.
When I did evaluate in debugger for criteria.list() I got correct response in hibernate 4 and when I evaluate criteria.list() in hiberante 5 then already in debugger I can see an error ORA-00904.
What changed between Hibernate 4 and Hibernate 5 in this case?

I hope any of below links helps in your migration.
I searched error mentioned in this post on google and found a reference to this baeldung blog
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-hibernate-projections that states
**Hibernate has deprecated its Criteria API from version 5.2 onwards in favour of the JPA CriteriaQuery API. **
So I opened documentation for Hibernate 5.1
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#d4e1
and in the Example 5.8. Specifying FetchMode on a query section
Important
Only fetch mode can be adjusted, refrain from applying any other restriction. While it is known to work as of Hibernate Search 4, using restriction (ie a where clause) on your Criteria query should be avoided when possible. getResultSize() will throw a SearchException if used in conjunction with a Criteria with restriction.
Also there is a migration guide
https://hibernate.org/search/documentation/migrate/5.0/ that states a warning at top - If you’re upgrading from older versions, please migrate to 4.5.3.Final first.

thanks @SharadPaul for you answer! It's helpful but even if criteria is deprecated it should not fail on criteria.list(). Deprecated mean that it can be removed in future Hibernate versions. I think I should focus on method list() implementation. Maybe I created sessionFactory in wrong way.
